# Saving values in the iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I'm new to xcode and programing, and I'm creating my first app using objective-c. My app consists of a timer, and now I would like my app to store all the results inside the app. I would like to be able to see all of the times and delete the ones I want.

How could I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is too broad for this site, but you're going to want to look into [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html).

Comment: Okay!! Thanks for your fast response!!